# Can I install postgresql8.2 via command prompt or running any batch or registry file?

Tags: windows, installation, postgresql-8.2

Is it possible to install the entire database(postgresql8.2) via command prompt or batch file or registry file bypassing the trivial procedure for installation. But then to a question comes that, how can we supply default parameters such as name,password,language,default location of database? Currently I'm working on 'Windows XP' platform.

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to migrate to superuser.com. You might want to specify your platform in the future (although it can be deducted from 'batch' and 'registry' in this case).

Comment: Why 8.2? 8.4 is much faster, takes less space and is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

For 8.3 and lower the obvious answer is: http://pginstaller.projects.pgfoundry.org/ which supports or supported silent installations.  For more recent versions, please read: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2135.page

Use of existing installers would simplify your life and be where I would start.

This being said there is no reason you can't generate a script to register dll's properly run initdb, etc.  This will take some extra knowledge of both PostgreSQL and Windows, and will be mostly suitable for custom solutions (i.e. not cases where you merely are packaging software that runs with PostgreSQL).  I don't think an complete answer can be given here because once you need such a solution you need to design your installation around if.  Books could be written on that topic.  The docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/install-windows.html should get you started however since the only difference really between installing from source and installing from the precompiled source is just that you need to compile the source files first.

Failing that you could take a look at the binary zip packages.  Typically these can be extracted and PostgreSQL can be run from inside them.